# Azure log api JavaScript sample

Tags: javascript, azure-log-analytics

I would like to log to a Azure Log Analytics workspace. I can see several examples of how to log [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api). Not having the time to research converting the given samples I was wondering if anyone has developed a similar sample using JavaScript that they would be willing to share?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my test, if you want to call HTTP Data Collector API, please refer to the following steps. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/data-collector-api).

1. [Get Share Key](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/loganalytics/workspaces/getsharedkeys)

```
az login
az account set --subscription <the subscription you use>
az monitor log-analytics workspace get-shared-keys --resource-group <> --workspace-name <>
```

2. Code

```
var crypto = require("crypto")
var request = require('request');
async function main() {
   var json = [
  {
    slot_ID: 12345,
    ID: "5cdad72f-c848-4df0-8aaa-ffe033e75d57",
    availability_Value: 100,
    performance_Value: 6.954,
    measurement_Name: "last_one_hour",
    duration: 3600,
    warning_Threshold: 0,
    critical_Threshold: 0,
    IsActive: "true",
  },
  {
    slot_ID: 67890,
    ID: "b6bee458-fb65-492e-996d-61c4d7fbb942",
    availability_Value: 100,
    performance_Value: 3.379,
    measurement_Name: "last_one_hour",
    duration: 3600,
    warning_Threshold: 0,
    critical_Threshold: 0,
    IsActive: "false",
  }
];

var body = JSON.stringify(json);
    var contentLength =Buffer.byteLength(body,'utf8');
    var key = ''
    var workspaceId = '';
    var apiVersion = '2016-04-01';
    var GMTTime = new Date().toUTCString()

    var StringToSign = 'POST' + '\n'
         + contentLength+'\n'
        + 'application/json' + '\n'
        +'x-ms-date:'+ GMTTime + '\n'
        + '/api/logs'  
    var Sig = crypto.createHmac('sha256', Buffer.from(key, 'base64')).update(StringToSign, 'utf-8').digest('base64');
    
    var authorization = 'SharedKey ' + workspaceId + ':' + Sig;
    var headers = {
        "Content-Type":"application/json",
        "Authorization": authorization,
        "Log-Type": 'demoexample',
        "x-ms-date": GMTTime,
        "time-generated-field" : new Date().toISOString
    };
    var url = 'https://' + workspaceId + '.ods.opinsights.azure.com/api/logs?api-version=' + apiVersion;
    request.post({ url: url, headers: headers, body: body }, function (error, response){

          if (error){
              console.log(error)

          }else{

            console.log(response.statusCode + "   " + response.statusMessage)
          }

    })
}

main()
```

[image]